List of different config files *after* do-release-upgrade
When you run do-release-upgrade it asks you if you want to replace your locally modified config files with the maintainers' ones. It's often difficult to decide quickly...
So is there a way to see that list after the install so I can manually check everything over ?

This question is similar to: Is it possible to find all the config file replacements done during apt-get?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, that answers the question. Thanks. How do I mark my question as a duplicate ?
